# Is there a way to generate dependencies into a package.json from a yarn.lock?

Tags: javascript, package.json, yarnpkg

I'm having trouble syncing my `yarn.lock` file with my `package.json` file. If I install my dependencies with `yarn install`, everything works fine. However, if I do `npm install`, I end up with some issues. Similarly, if I delete this `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install`, I get those issues as well.

This tells me that there is some issue in my `package.json` dependencies versions and I've been trying to figure out what is wrong. Is there a way I can remove what I have listed in my `package.json` and just generate it from my working `yarn.lock` file? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding dependencies with yarn and npm? Can't you manage all your deps with yarn?

Comment: _"some issues"_ should be elaborated.